# Power BI Map Values are not updating

Tags: powerbi, analytics

I copied an old Power BI Report and gave it a new source. The new source has the same columns but updated data.
The Map of the USA on the NEW PBI report I made does not change the values by state, it gives it to max value, i.e. all the states say 4,100 instead of different number.
The filters all match, what else should I check?

Comment: Sounds like you corrupted the data model by "giving a new source." How exactly did you do that?

Comment: @Peter all I did was replace the data source - I ensured the columns were the same. Should I try a different way?

Comment: @Peter Thank you! It worked. I used the same data source (excel workbook) and pasted the new data and it updated everything accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "replace" a query by another one with the same name, the data model will be broken. What you need to do is "edit" an existing query and "paste in" the new code. You can do that by opening both queries in the PQ *Advanced Editor*. Of cause the new code has to result in the same column structure.

Comment: By data source, I meant a new Excel file not new code. Does that change anything? So I basically have an updated Excel workbook, and I replaced the old one with my new one.